# how do I specify nested CanCan authorizations with non-standard relationship names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, nested-resources

I'm using Devise for authentication and CanCan for authorization.

### the goal

I have two models: User and Sponsorship, where Sponsorship provides a has_many :through relationship between user-as-sponsor and user-as-client.

I want to configure CanCan so a user with `sponsor?` privileges can manage his or her own Sponsorships, that is, only sponsorships for which `Sponsorship#client_id == user.id`. A user can also have `admin?` privileges, in which case he or she can manage any Sponsorship.

### the models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sponsor_links, :class_name => 'Sponsorship', :foreign_key => 'client_id'
  has_many :sponsors, :through => :sponsor_links, :class_name => 'User'

  has_many :client_links, :class_name => 'Sponsorship', :foreign_key => 'sponsor_id'
  has_many :clients, :through => :client_links, :class_name => 'User'

  def has_role?(role)
    ... return true if this user has <role> privileges
  end
end

class Sponsorship
  belongs_to :sponsor, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => 'User'
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new  # handle guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role?(:admin)
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role?(:sponsor)
      # not sure if the third argument is correct...
      can :manage, Sponsorship, :sponsor => {:user_id => user.id}
    end
  end
end
```

### the routes

I've set up nested routes to reflect the fact that a sponsoring user owns his or her clients:

```
resource :users, :only => [:index]
  resource :sponsorships
end
```

### the question

What's the right way to load and authorize the user and sponsorship resources in my SponsorshipsController?

### what I've tried

This is similar to an ordinary nested resource, which CanCan handles easily.  But the relations have non-standard names (e.g. :sponsor_links rather than :sponsorships), and I haven't figured out how to configure the `load_and_authorize_resource` declarations in my SponsorshipsController.

Among the many things I've tried that don't work ;), here's one of the simpler versions.  (Note also that my Abilities may not be set up properly -- see above):

```
class SponsorshipsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :sponsor_links, :class_name => "User"
  load_and_authorize_resource :sponsorships, :through => :sponsor_links
  respond_to :json

  # GET /users/:user_id/sponsorships.json
  def index
    respond_to @sponsorships
  end

  # GET /users/:user_id/sponsorships/:id.json
  def show
    respond_to @sponsorship
  end
end
```

By rescuing CanCan::AccessDenied errors, I know that:

- In `index` with a `:sponsor` user, authentication fails for the User.
- In `index` with an `:admin` user, authentication fails for the Sponsorship.
- In `show`, regardless of the role, authentication fails for the Sponsorship.

Answer (score 1):

### a partial answer

First problem was in the Abilities spec, which read:

```
...if user.has_role?(:sponsor)
  can :manage, Sponsorship, :sponsor => {:user_id => user.id}
end
```

but should have just been

```
...if user.has_role?(:sponsor)
  can :manage, Sponsorship, :user_id => user.id
end
```

(Remember, kids, [unit tests](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities) are your friend!  Somehow I'd forgotten that lesson.)

In the controller, I also changed:

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :sponsor_links, :class_name => "User"
  load_and_authorize_resource :sponsorships, :through => :sponsor_links
```

to just

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :sponsorship
```

This *mostly* works: it sets up @user and @sponsorship and authorizes access to them.  But the index function loads all sponsorships accessible to the current_user, not just those owned by :user_id.  My fix -- probably not optimal -- was to rewrite the index function from

```
  def index
    respond_with(@user, @sponsorships)
  end
```

to

```
  def index
    @sponsorships = @sponsorships.where(:sponsor_id => @user.id)
    respond_with(@user, @sponsorships)
  end
```

With these changes, it all works.

If someone has a more proper way to express this, I'd like to know.